# MySql cursors.execute() with only one parameter: Why is a string sliced into a list?

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-connector-python

### Status Quo:

I have a working database with tables and can query, insert, update, etc. Also the cursor is connected to the right database.

The table:

[image: screenshot of query result]

### Problem:

When it comes to querying data from a table I run into trouble:

```
query     = 'SELECT Last_Request_Time FROM Products WHERE idProduct = %s'
idProduct = '106'
cursor.execute(query, (idProduct))
```

While debugging I have a look at the cursor.execute() function: `params = str: 106` will be passed to:

```
stmt = operation % self._process_params(params)
```

where

```
res = params
# pylint: disable=W0141
res = map(self._connection.converter.to_mysql, res)
```

is called with `res = str: 106`. I am not sure what the converter is doing but as result **`res = list: ['1', '0', '6']`**. And these arguments will be passed to the execute function which will run into following error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 480, in execute
"Wrong number of arguments during string formatting")
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Wrong number of arguments during string formatting
```

### Bad workaround:

I have a dirty workaround, but I am not happy with it. It may not work in some cases:

```
query     = 'SELECT Last_Request_Time FROM Products WHERE idProduct = %s AND Edition != %s'
idProduct = '106'
cursor.execute(query, (idProduct, 'A'))
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that `('hello')` is a string and `('hello',)` is a *tuple*. You need to always pass a tuple (or other such collection, like a list) as the values for your placeholders.  The reason is that your placeholders are *positional* in your query, so the arguments should also have some order - and tuples and lists are two ways to get an ordered selection of objects.

Since its expecting a tuple or other collection, `106` gets converted to `[1, 0, 6]`. If you pass in `(106,)`, it will be interpreted correctly.

Behind the scenes, this is what is going on:

```
>>> for i in '106':
...     print(i)
...
1
0
6
>>> for i in ('106',):
...    print(i)
...
106
```

So, your 'hack' is actually the correct solution, you just don't need the extra variable:

```
q = 'SELECT Last_Request_Time FROM Products WHERE idProduct = %s'
cursor.execute(q, (idProduct,))
```

Comment: That was a quick answer!
I tried to make a list/tuple out of it, but couldn't find the solution. But this one was kinda easy. So there a much things to learn, when it comes down to python.